# Python script ran OK for weeks using cron job and it's now giving a KeyError

Tags: python, macos, web-scraping, cron

Here's the code I'm trying to run. Works when executed from PyCharm. I set up a cronjob and it worked wonders for weeks. It's now giving a KeyError out of the bloom. Can't find what's wrong since I haven't touched anything in the cronjob.

```
import csv
import json
import os
import random
import time
from urllib.parse import urlencode

import requests


API_URL = "https://community.koodomobile.com/widget/pointsLeaderboard?"
LEADERBOARD_FILE = "leaderboard_data.json"


def get_leaderboard(period: str = "allTime", max_results: int = 20) -> list:
    payload = {"period": period, "maxResults": max_results}
    return requests.get(f"{API_URL}{urlencode(payload)}").json()


def dump_leaderboard_data(leaderboard_data: dict) -> None:
    with open("leaderboard_data.json", "w") as jf:
        json.dump(leaderboard_data, jf, indent=4, sort_keys=True)


def read_leaderboard_data(data_file: str) -> dict:
    with open(data_file) as f:
        return json.load(f)


def parse_leaderboard(leaderboard: list) -> dict:
    return {
        item["name"]: {
            "id": item["id"],
            "score_data": {
                time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"): item["points"],
            },
            "rank": item["leaderboardPosition"],
        } for item in leaderboard
    }


def update_leaderboard_data(target: dict, new_data: dict) -> dict:
    for player, stats in new_data.items():
        target[player]["rank"] = stats["rank"]
        target[player]["score_data"].update(stats["score_data"])
    return target


def leaderboard_to_csv(leaderboard: dict) -> None:
    data_rows = [
        [player] + list(stats["score_data"].values()) 
        for player, stats in leaderboard.items()
    ]
    random_player = random.choice(list(leaderboard.keys()))
    dates = list(leaderboard[random_player]["score_data"])
    with open("the_data.csv", "w") as output:
        w = csv.writer(output)
        w.writerow([""] + dates)
        w.writerows(data_rows)


def script_runner():
    if os.path.isfile(LEADERBOARD_FILE):
        fresh_data = update_leaderboard_data(
            target=read_leaderboard_data(LEADERBOARD_FILE),
            new_data=parse_leaderboard(get_leaderboard()),
        )
        leaderboard_to_csv(fresh_data)
        dump_leaderboard_data(fresh_data)
    else:
        dump_leaderboard_data(parse_leaderboard(get_leaderboard()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    script_runner()
```

Here's the error taht it gives me. Seems like there's a problem with dictionary hence the KeyError.

```
  File "/Users/Rob/PycharmProjects/Koodo/TEST.Json.py", line 75, in <module>
    script_runner()
  File "/Users/Rob/PycharmProjects/Koodo/TEST.Json.py", line 64, in script_runner
    fresh_data = update_leaderboard_data(
  File "/Users/Rob/PycharmProjects/Koodo/TEST.Json.py", line 44, in update_leaderboard_data
    target[player]["rank"] = stats["rank"]
KeyError: 'triggered123'
```

Here's the data in JSON file : https://pastebin.com/HQyL4Kyx

Answer (score 0):

That's because the key named `triggered123` is NOT present in the dictionary `target`.

Source: https://wiki.python.org/moin/KeyError

The problem is that in `update_leaderboard_data` you iterate over the new data and use them to lookup in the old data. If a new key does not already exists in the old data, you'll get the `KeyError`.

Try to print the dict `target` to see if the key `triggered123` is in it.

Or use the `get` method of the `dict` with a default value: so no error wil be raised, and you'll be able to search this default value in your output.

Comment: When I open leaderboard_data.json file, triggered is definitely there. See edit

Comment: `triggered` or `triggered123` ?

Comment: It is triggered123 I was talking about

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like the first time your code is run, it caches the leaderboard.

On subsequent runs, it will update the existing leaderboard with the new values, by looping over each of the new entries, finding their username, and looking up that key in the older dictionary. However, if there's a new user, that key will not exist in the old dictionary.

You're getting the error because the player `triggered123` is a new user to the leaderboard, and was listed after you first ran the script.

You need to update `update_leaderboard_data` to handle this case (by checking if the key exists in the dictionary before attempting to access it).

Comment: I did understand that was the problem. This is the reason I deleted the json file so triggered IS in the cache. Which he currently is. Still give out this error while running the cronjob ONLY. PyCharm script works. That's why I get confused. Does cron save the cache elsewhere? EDIT : I think I found the issue. When running from cron tab the file is created elsewhere.

Comment: Unless you change it, your working directory is your home directory for cronjobs, so `/home/<username>/leaderboard_data.json` (or `~/leaderboard_data.json` for short)